# How did Merry and Pippin get their Barrow blades back?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

The swords that the Hobbits got from the Barrow-downs were apparently magical in some way: in "The Departure of Boromir", Aragorn says this of Merry and Pippin's blades:

> Doubtless the Orcs despoiled them, but feared to keep the knives, knowing them for what they are: work of Westernesse, wound about with spells for the bane of Mordor.

There are several reasons to believe that the Barrow-blades were particularly harmful to the Nazgûl. A major piece of evidence is the effect of Merry's blade on the Witch-king during the Battle of the Pelennor Fields. It was enchanted with the power to harm the Witch-king of Angmar himself.

We know almost nothing about whether the Barrow-blades had any special effect on other evil creatures. In "Flotsam and Jetsam", Merry says that Uglúk (leader of the Uruk-hai band) took the swords but then "threw the things away as if they burned him."

(Details of question quoted from [here](https://stason.org/TULARC/education-books/tolkien-newsgroups/45-Were-the-barrow-blades-magical-In-what-way-Tolkien.html#.UXlaMXfn_mI#ixzz2RUfmq0BO).)

With that said, how did the Hobbits get their Barrow-blades back if the Uruks threw them away after Merry and Pippin were captured?

Comment: I think you are over-interpreting a little: nowhere is it suggested that the blade was made *specifically* to kill the Witch King of Angmar, only that it was forged at the time when Kingdom of Angmar was the chief foe of the Northern Kingdom.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Aragorn found them and returned them at Isengard in 'Flotsam and Jetsam'.

> 'Here are some treasures that you let fall' said Aragorn. 'You will
>   be glad to have them back.' He loosened his belt from under his cloak,
>   and took from it the two sheathed knives.

This is near the beginning of the chapter.

Comment: Oh man, that was right in front of Merry's comment about Ugluk taking them. Duh. I'm getting too old. Thanks Derek.